# Starting Yesod without environment flag using mod_fastcgi

Tags: haskell, fastcgi, yesod

To launch my Yesod application I need to provide an application environment argument for example:

./myYesodApp Production

Is there any way using Yesod to start the application and have the environment set as an environment variable or a configuration setting? So I can simply call:

./myYesodApp

I need to be able to do this so I can run my Yesod app using mod_fastcgi.

Alternatively is there any way to provide this argument to FastCgiWrapper?

My main.hs looks like this:

```
import Prelude              (IO, (>>=))
import Yesod.Default.Config (fromArgs)
import Yesod.Default.Main   (defaultMain)
import Settings             (parseExtra)
import Application          (makeApplication)
import Network.Wai.Handler.FastCGI (run)

main :: IO ()
main = fromArgs parseExtra >>= makeApplication >>= run
```

Comment: What's your Yesod main look like?  Is there a reason you can't use `System.Environment.getEnv` in the beginning of `main` to check an environment variable?

Comment: I have added my main.hs to the question. How can I inject the variable in here so the Yesod framework uses it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `withArgs :: [String] -> IO a -> IO a` from `System.Environment` will be the easiest way to do this.

```
main = do
   env <- getEnv "YESOD_ENVIRONMENT"
   withArgs [env] (fromArgs parseExtra >>= makeApplication >>= run)
```

Comment: I get the error: `appEnv' is not a (visible) constructor field name.

It looks to be defined here: https://github.com/yesodweb/yesod/blob/master/yesod/Yesod/Default/Config.hs

Any ideas?

Comment: I edited my answer, as I was looking at the Yesod code I found a much simpler solution than setting up the config.